# Let C3[t] be the space of polynomials of degree at least 3. Consider the map ψ:C3[t]→C3[t] given by p7→[(p(−1)p(0)p(1)]∗Column Vector.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $C^3[t]$ be the space of polynomials of degree at least $3$. Consider the map $\psi : C^3[t] \to C^3[t]$ given by $p_7 \to [( p(−1) p(0) p(1)]*\text{Column Vector}$.

1. Show that $\psi$ is $C$-linear. Begin your answer by stating the condition(s) you have to check.
2. Show that the set $\beta = \{2t^3 + 1, t^3 + t−1, t^2 −1, t^3 −t\} \subseteq C^3[t]$ is linearly independent. Begin your answer by stating the condition(s) you have to check. Show that $\beta$ is a basis of $C^3[t]$.
3. Compute the basis representation $[\psi] \gamma \beta$ of $\psi$ with respect to the basis $\beta$ of $C^3[t]$ and $\gamma =([1 0 0],[ 0 i 0] ,[ 1 0 1])*\text{Column Vectors}$ of $C^3$. You do not need to show that $\gamma$ is a basis of C3.
4. Is $\psi$ injective? Justify your answer.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! I think there are some concepts which need clarification. What is $p7$? What is $\gamma$? Is it a $3 \times 3$ matrix, with $[100]$ being its first row? What about column vectors? If you could please, elaborate.

Comment: Sorry p7 is a mistake its just p, γ is a set with 3 column vectors in